# Any way to speedup itertool.product

Tags: python, numpy, nested-loops, python-itertools

I am using itertools.product to find the possible weights an asset can take given that the sum of all weights adds up to 100.

```
min_wt = 10
max_wt = 50
step = 10
nb_Assets = 5

weight_mat = []
for i in itertools.product(range(min_wt, (max_wt+1), step), repeat = nb_Assets):
    if sum(i) == 100:
        weight = [i]
        if np.shape(weight_mat)[0] == 0:
            weight_mat = weight
        else:
            weight_mat = np.concatenate((weight_mat, weight), axis = 0)
```

The above code works, but it is too slow as it goes through the combinations that are not acceptable, example [50,50,50,50,50] eventually testing 3125 combinations instead of 121 possible combinations. Is there any way we can add the 'sum' condition within the loop to speed things up?

Comment: At the very top of the loop you could have an `if` that filters out illegal values. What decides if a combo is valid or not?

Comment: Repeated `np.concatenate` is slow.  Use list append instead.

Comment: Does the order matter? That is, is `[50, 20, 10, 10, 10]` the same as `[10, 10, 10, 20, 50]`? (and therefore only one of them should be produced)

Comment: For the given input size, using simple `list.append()` instead of `np.concatenate()` already doubles the speed (code takes about half the time). I made these comparissons in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58824199/9225671).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparing performance of the offered solutions:

```
import itertools
import timeit
import numpy as np


# original code from question
def f1():
    min_wt = 10
    max_wt = 50
    step = 10
    nb_assets = 5

    weight_mat = []
    for i in itertools.product(range(min_wt, (max_wt+1), step), repeat=nb_assets):
        if sum(i) == 100:
            weight = [i, ]
            if np.shape(weight_mat)[0] == 0:
                weight_mat = weight
            else:
                weight_mat = np.concatenate((weight_mat, weight), axis=0)

    return weight_mat


# code from question using list instead of numpy array
def f1b():
    min_wt = 10
    max_wt = 50
    step = 10
    nb_assets = 5

    weight_list = []
    for i in itertools.product(range(min_wt, (max_wt+1), step), repeat=nb_assets):
        if sum(i) == 100:
            weight_list.append(i)

    return weight_list


# calculating the last element of each tuple
def f2():
    min_wt = 10
    max_wt = 50
    step = 10
    nb_assets = 5

    weight_list = []
    for i in itertools.product(range(min_wt, (max_wt+1), step), repeat=nb_assets-1):
        the_sum = sum(i)
        if the_sum < 100:
            last_elem = 100 - the_sum
            if min_wt <= last_elem <= max_wt:
                weight_list.append(i + (last_elem, ))

    return weight_list


# recursive solution from user kaya3 (https://stackoverflow.com/a/58823843/9225671)
def constrained_partitions(n, k, min_w, max_w, w_step=1):
    if k < 0:
        raise ValueError('Number of parts must be at least 0')
    elif k == 0:
        if n == 0:
            yield ()
    else:
        for w in range(min_w, max_w+1, w_step):
            for p in constrained_partitions(n-w, k-1, min_w, max_w, w_step):
                yield (w,) + p

def f3():
    return list(constrained_partitions(100, 5, 10, 50, 10))


# recursive solution from user jdehesa (https://stackoverflow.com/a/58823990/9225671)
def make_weight_combs(min_wt, max_wt, step, nb_assets, req_wt):
    weights = range(min_wt, max_wt + 1, step)
    current = []
    yield from _make_weight_combs_rec(weights, nb_assets, req_wt, current)

def _make_weight_combs_rec(weights, nb_assets, req_wt, current):
    if nb_assets <= 0:
        yield tuple(current)
    else:
        # Discard weights that cannot possibly be used
        while weights and weights[0] + weights[-1] * (nb_assets - 1) < req_wt:
            weights = weights[1:]
        while weights and weights[-1] + weights[0] * (nb_assets - 1) > req_wt:
            weights = weights[:-1]
        # Add all possible weights
        for w in weights:
            current.append(w)
            yield from _make_weight_combs_rec(weights, nb_assets - 1, req_wt - w, current)
            current.pop()

def f4():
    return list(make_weight_combs(10, 50, 10, 5, 100))
```

I tested these functions using `timeit` like this:

```
print(timeit.timeit('f()', 'from __main__ import f1 as f', number=100))
```

The results using the parameters from the question:

```
# min_wt = 10
# max_wt = 50
# step = 10
# nb_assets = 5
0.07021828400320373       # f1 - original code from question
0.041302188008558005      # f1b - code from question using list instead of numpy array
0.009902548001264222      # f2 - calculating the last element of each tuple
0.10601829699589871       # f3 - recursive solution from user kaya3
0.03329997700348031       # f4 - recursive solution from user jdehesa
```

If I expand the search space (reduced step and increased assets):

```
# min_wt = 10
# max_wt = 50
# step = 5
# nb_assets = 6
7.6620834979985375        # f1 - original code from question
7.31425816299452          # f1b - code from question using list instead of numpy array
0.809070186005556         # f2 - calculating the last element of each tuple
14.88188026699936         # f3 - recursive solution from user kaya3
0.39385621099791024       # f4 - recursive solution from user jdehesa
```

Seems like `f2` and `f4` are the fastest (for the tested size of the data).

Comment: Thanks a lot Ralf (and everyone else).. the analysis of all the functions really helped!

Answer (score 4):

Many improvements are possible.

For starters, the search space can be reduced using *itertools.combinations_with_replacement()* because summation is commutative.

Also, the last addend should be computed rather than tested.  For example if `t[:4]` was `(10, 20, 30, 35)`, you could compute `t[4]` as `1 - sum(t)`, giving a value of *5*.  This will give a 100-fold speed-up over trying one-hundred values of *x* in `(10, 20, 30, 35, x)`.

Comment: I implemented one of you suggestions and compared it to other proposals in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58824199/9225671); it works quite well.

Answer (score 3):

You can write up a recursive algorithm for that which prunes all the impossible options early on:

```
def make_weight_combs(min_wt, max_wt, step, nb_assets, req_wt):
    weights = range(min_wt, max_wt + 1, step)
    current = []
    yield from _make_weight_combs_rec(weights, nb_assets, req_wt, current)

def _make_weight_combs_rec(weights, nb_assets, req_wt, current):
    if nb_assets <= 0:
        yield tuple(current)
    else:
        # Discard weights that cannot possibly be used
        while weights and weights[0] + weights[-1] * (nb_assets - 1) < req_wt:
            weights = weights[1:]
        while weights and weights[-1] + weights[0] * (nb_assets - 1) > req_wt:
            weights = weights[:-1]
        # Add all possible weights
        for w in weights:
            current.append(w)
            yield from _make_weight_combs_rec(weights, nb_assets - 1, req_wt - w, current)
            current.pop()

min_wt = 10
max_wt = 50
step = 10
nb_assets = 5
req_wt = 100
for comb in make_weight_combs(min_wt, max_wt, step, nb_assets, req_wt):
    print(comb, sum(comb))
```

Output:

```
(10, 10, 10, 20, 50) 100
(10, 10, 10, 30, 40) 100
(10, 10, 10, 40, 30) 100
(10, 10, 10, 50, 20) 100
(10, 10, 20, 10, 50) 100
(10, 10, 20, 20, 40) 100
(10, 10, 20, 30, 30) 100
(10, 10, 20, 40, 20) 100
...
```

If order of the weights does not matter (so, for example, `(10, 10, 10, 20, 50)` and `(50, 20, 10, 10, 10)` are the same), then you can modify the `for` loop as follows:

```
for i, w in enumerate(weights):
    current.append(w)
    yield from _make_weight_combs_rec(weights[i:], nb_assets - 1, req_wt - w, current)
    current.pop()
```

Which gives the output:

```
(10, 10, 10, 20, 50) 100
(10, 10, 10, 30, 40) 100
(10, 10, 20, 20, 40) 100
(10, 10, 20, 30, 30) 100
(10, 20, 20, 20, 30) 100
(20, 20, 20, 20, 20) 100
```

Comment: I compared your proposal to other suggestions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58824199/9225671); your solution works quite well.

Answer (score 2):

Let's generalise this problem; you want to iterate over k-tuples whose sum is n, and whose elements are within `range(min_w, max_w+1, w_step)`. This is a kind of [integer partitioning problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)), with some extra constraints on the size of the partition and the sizes of its components.

To do this, we can write a recursive generator function; for each `w` in the range, the remainder of the tuple is a (k - 1)-tuple whose sum is (n - w). The base case is a 0-tuple, which is possible only if the required sum is 0.

As Raymond Hettinger notes, you can also improve the efficiency when k = 1 by just testing whether the required sum is one of the allowed weights.

```py
def constrained_partitions(n, k, min_w, max_w, w_step=1):
    if k < 0:
        raise ValueError('Number of parts must be at least 0')
    elif k == 0:
        if n == 0:
            yield ()
    elif k == 1:
        if n in range(min_w, max_w+1, w_step):
            yield (n,)
    elif min_w*k <= n <= max_w*k:
        for w in range(min_w, max_w+1, w_step):
            for p in constrained_partitions(n-w, k-1, min_w, max_w, w_step):
                yield (w,) + p
```

Usage:

```py
>>> for p in constrained_partitions(5, 3, 1, 5, 1):
...     print(p)
...
(1, 1, 3)
(1, 2, 2)
(1, 3, 1)
(2, 1, 2)
(2, 2, 1)
(3, 1, 1)
>>> len(list(constrained_partitions(100, 5, 10, 50, 10)))
121
```

Whenever you're iterating over all solutions to some sort of combinatorial problem, it's generally best to generate actual solutions directly, rather than generate more than you need (e.g. with `product` or `combinations_with_replacement`) and reject the ones you don't want. For larger inputs, the vast majority of time would be spent generating solutions which will get rejected, due to [combinatorial explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_explosion).

Note that if you don't want repeats in different orders (e.g. `1, 1, 3` and `1, 3, 1`), you can change the recursive call to `constrained_partitions(n-w, k-1, min_w, w, w_step)` to only generate partitions where the weights are in non-increasing order.

Comment: I compared your proposal to other suggestions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58824199/9225671); your solution works, but is a bit slow (at least for this input size).

Comment: Thanks @Ralf. I updated the code to handle the case `k = 1` more efficiently, and using your timing code I now get similar results to @jdehesa's solution. However, mine is clearly slower for larger inputs due to being less-well optimised (`yield` is slower than `yield from` for recursive generators).

Comment: Made a further optimisation to check for `min_w*k <= n <= max_w*k`. I realised that without this check, my code *was* generating all combinations and rejecting those with the wrong sum (like the original `itertools.product` solution does). It's now very comparable to @jdehesa's solution, but mine is still marginally slower. I'll accept defeat on this one for now, though!

Answer (score 1):

Note that when you have *N* weights that sum up to 100, and you chose *N - 1* weights, the remaining weight is already defined as 100 - sum of already chosen weights, which should be positive. The same limitation applies to any number of already chosen weights.

Next, you don't want combinations that are just permutations of the same weights. This is why you can order weights by value, and choose the next weight in the combination to be below or equal of the previous one.

This immediately makes the search space much smaller, and you can break a particular branch of search earlier.

Probably writing it with explicit loops first, or as a recursive algorithm, should be much easier for understanding and implementing.

Comment: *"Next, you don't want combinations that are just permutations of the same weights."* That's an assumption that isn't present in the question. Whether or not repeats in different permutations are wanted depends on the use case.

Comment: @kaya3: The initial question is an example of an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). If permutations are needed in the output, they can be more readily generated from each combination found.

Comment: I don't think it's an XY problem; the OP says there should be 121 results, which is correct if different permutations are counted separately but not if permutations are excluded. It's also simpler to generate permutations in the first place, rather than exclude them and then generate them in a separate stage.